# filling appropriate textBox depending on variable

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I got this code:

```
if (variable == 1) { textBox1.Text = ""; }
else if (variable == 2) { textBox2.Text = ""; }
else if (variable == 3) { textBox3.Text = ""; }
etc.
```

Is there a way, how to fill appropriate textBox depending on variable?
Something like this:

```
textBox.variable = "";
```

this is C# code but both Visual Basic and C# answers would help very much

Comment: Just set textBox1.Text = variable;

Comment: @CDVAProgrammer That's not what OP is asking, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ah, apologies I misread it.  You're response below is the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or in little bid more readable manner by using `Dictionary`, which is not based on the order.

```
var textboxes = new Dictionary<int, TextBox>
{
    { 1, textBox1 },
    { 2, textBox2 },
    { 3, textBox3 }
};

textboxes[variable].Text = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put text boxes in an array, and use index to access it:

```
TextBox[] textBoxes = new[] {null, textBox1, textBox2, textBox3};
// Skip index zero -----------^
```

Now you can access them as follows:

```
textBoxes[variable].Text = "Hello";
```